# Is there a canonical source for retrieving Material Safety Data Sheets?

Tags: toxicity

Is there a convenient, easy-to-access source for Material Safety Data Sheets (MSDSes) that does not require registration or payment?

A good website or reference book for wood-working MSDSes should make it easy to look up:

- Products by manufacturer or brand name (such as Copper-Green Brown)
- Products by chemical name (such as copper naphthenate)
- Include a wide variety of wood working materials, glues, and finishes
- Not require registration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, although such a resource would be valuable, questions seeking links to off-site resources are generally not permitted on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Vote to close. Because what is required is google to find the answer. Any answer we could provide would just be a link only answer. A specific question about a MSDS for a particular wood, would not be answerable here because what you need for the answer is MSDS to answer in question in this context. In other words the expert answer is the MSDS, and we could not duplicate that.

Comment: Voting to reopen. While I agree that "questions seeking links" are bad,  shopping questions are also for the same reasons.  There is no chance that this site will ever be a host for MSDS (most significant site issues deal with topics that are fully in scope), Robs answer is good and in scope, (with room for improvement) "No, the site does not exist, but here is what to look for".  This is the same as a shopping type question where answers revolve  around what to look for in a tool, not the tool its self.

Comment: If you strongly disagree with my re-open proposal or want to discuss it more, please open a Meta discussion and link to it in the comments here.

Comment: I edited the post slightly to try to avoid the "just post a link" issue with the question.  If the community dislikes it, please feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: I think that the question as stated in the title is on topic.  I think the question as stated in the question is off topic, probably.  A canonical source would be something like an OSHA website, something that was not a private company but was actually a core resource where MSDSs are registered.

Comment: @Joe I wonder if it could be phrased, "How does one find MSDSs" where answers could potentially be "The canonical source is..." or "They are often provided by resellers, e.g., ...", etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's required by law, but many companies make their MSDSes publicly available for free.

For example:

- http://www.titebond.com/ProductMSDSCO.php
- http://msds.gp.com/msdsinternet/?bu=bp

In addition, some resellers provide the MSDSes for products they sell:

- http://www.highlandwoodworking.com/material-safety-datasheets-msds.aspx

You can also often find the MSDS for a product or chemical by searching for the product or chemical name along with "msds" in Google, Bing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can currently do is search Google (or Duck, or Bing) for the product name, followed by MSDS.  For example:

- Googling:  [Copper Green Brown MSDS](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Copper%20Green%20Brown%20MSDS) gives the [MSDS](http://www.coppergreen.com/wpscg.htm) as the first link.
- Ducking:  [Copper Green Brown MSDS](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Copper%20Green%20Brown%20MSDS) also gives the [MSDS](http://www.coppergreen.com/wpscg.htm) as the first link.